# Objective C : Show contextual menu on left click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, contextmenu

I have a contextual menu on a NSImageView which is displayed when the user right clicks on the NSImageView. I would also like it to be displayed when a user left clicks. The menu is created  using the IB and is linked up to the NSImageView via the IB.

I thought about "calling" the right click event, but I couldn't find any useful information about that.

Comment: Have you considered reading the Cocoa Event-Handling Guide in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks, I did have a look at the docs... but still couldn't find anything I could use.... I'm missing something really obvious. I'll get some sleep and look again tomorrow, maybe I'll spot it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the following, where `view` is your image view:

```
NSPoint location = [view convertPoint:event.locationInWindow fromView:nil];
[view.menu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:location inView:view];
```

Comment: Hahahaha, Necro of the year.